# How to insert before update query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, concurrency

I had run two threads, one for insert another one for update in MySQL. The two operations are performed concurrently, my problem was the insert operation will performed first (before insert the update operation will be restricted) before update operation.

Comment: You can use wait/notify the thread which is updating the details should wait until notified by the thread which is actually creating the record.

Comment: please upload a code snippets

Answer (score 0):

create a new trigger, you use the CREATE TRIGGER statement. The following illustrates the syntax of the  CREATE TRIGGER statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event
ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
END;
```

Create a trigger after insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER occupy_trig AFTER INSERT ON occupiedroom 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
//update query
  UPDATE BookingRequest
     SET status = 1
   WHERE idRequest = NEW.idRequest;
 END
```

learn more about triggers at [techonthenet.com](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php)

Comment: if you find my answer usefull don't forget to upvote and accept :)